# Problem with fontsize when using longtable

Tags: tables, fontsize, longtable

I am using `longtable` package to make my large table span two pages. However I have set the font size with `\fontsize` to my table to be quite small. The only problem is that when the table is finished, the text below it are also the small size.

```
\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
\centering
\begin{longtable}{| p{.20\textwidth} | p{.80\textwidth} |} 
\hline
foo & bar \\ \hline 
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
\caption{Your caption here}
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}
```

(The above code was for test purposes as I was working from a tutorial)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`\fontsize` is defined as:

```
\fontsize{size}{skip}
```

The two arguments to \fontsize are the actual font size in `size` and the size of the baseline-skip in `skip`. The baseline-skip should be set to roughly 1.2x the font size. [Reference](https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/)

The declaration

```
\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
```

affects all following text until the end of the current group, the fact that there is a longtable there isn't that relevant.  You can use `\normalsize` to reset it or use `{` and `}` to limit the scope.  It really is better to use `\small` or other named sizes to get consistent sizing rather than setting each table to individually set point sizes. The scoping rules would apply to `\small` as well.

Comment: Hi, may you explain what 9 and 11 each represents? Thanks!

Comment: @JamesH 9pt font with 11pt between lines of text

Answer (score 16):

Enclose the `longtable` within `\begin{small}` and `\end{small}`, this will ensure the text to be of small size. Worked well for me. Or start the `longtable` with `\small`, ending it with `\normalsize` where the table ends.

Comment: `\small` is not an environment. don't use it on such a way.

Comment: why not use small as an environment? seems to work fine, and much less annoying than forgetting to \normalsize afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to change horizontal alignments to make the `longtable` wider, so it could fit without a need for a very small font-size.

I had a problem with other answers posted here today, they will also change the [longtable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) caption size! You can fix that using the [caption package](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) by adding this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{font=normalsize} % This will fix captions being resized
```

Then you can use your longtable like already suggested by others:

```
{ % Don't forget to limit the scope
\tiny % Or other fontsize modifier

\setlength\LTleft{-4.0cm}  % Change horizontal alignments
\setlength\LTright{-4.0cm} % ... to make longtable wider
\begin{longtable}{  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}| p{.20\textwidth} | p{.80\textwidth} |} 
\hline
foo & bar \\ \hline 
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
\caption{This caption WON'T have its size modified!}
\label{tab:longtable_with_normalsize_captions}
\end{longtable}
} % Don't forget to limit the scope
```